# Number of Distinct Elements in a Finite Field

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

I'm working on this question:

> For any element $a \in GF(p,(P(x))$, let $r(a)$ denote the number of *distinct* elements $b$ in $GF(p,P(x))$ such that $b^{p-1} = a.$ Show that if $a \neq 0$, then $r(a) = 0$ or $r(a)=p  -1$.

I have a feeling that Fermat's Little Theorem would come into play here, but that is my only lead for this problem. How should one approach this problem?

Comment: I've never seen this notation "$GF(p,(P(x))$" before. Can you spell out what it means?

Comment: I really never liked the notation myself. "$GF(p, P(x))$" stands for a Galois Field, where $p$ is the characteristic of $\mathbb{Z_p}$ and P(x) is a polynomial.

Comment: My professor uses this notation throughout his lecture, but I've seen other notations as well on this site.

Comment: There was a typo on the question, but it's been fixed by RJM.

Comment: One should approach the problem with the insight that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic.  So if the field has $p^n$ elements, the multiplicative group has one fewer (because we only omit zero).

Comment: @hardmath Yes I agree with you on that. I've actually encountered this situation on my previous exercises now that I recall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Fermat's little theorem in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ you have $a^{p-1}=1$ for all $a\ne 0$. Now let $F$ be any field containing $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and $a\in F^\times$. Let $b^{p-1}=a$ for some $b\ne 0$. Then $b^{p-1},(2b)^{p-1},\dots,((p-1)b)^{p-1}=a$ so you have at least $p-1$ roots, and $x^{p-1}-a=0$ can have at most $p-1$ roots, so $r(a)=p-1$.

Comment: $x^{p-1}-a = \prod_{n=1}^{p-1} (x-nb)$ where $b^{p-1} = a$

Comment: @RJM what notation is that? $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Definitions.2C_first_examples.2C_and_basic_properties @i8Σπ_821

Comment: Ahhh okay okay. With that in mind, this proof suffices.

Comment: Honestly I like the Wiki notation better than the one in my book. So from now on, I'll start using it.

Comment: I suspect that the notation in your book is intended to be more general than the notation $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.  When $p$ is prime the latter is a field with exactly $p$ elements.  Most likely the notation in your book, $GF(p,(P(x))$ is intended to apply to $p$ prime and $P(x)$ a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ which is *irreducible*.  Then the quotient ring of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[x]$ by the principal ideal generated by $P(x)$ will be a finite field containing $p^n$ elements where $n$ is the degree of $P(x)$.